# Unable to download file using phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, headless-browser

When I click on a button in chrome, it downloads a jpg file.
But when I am using phantomjs it doesn't download the jpg nor gives any error.

example: https://deepak5j.github.io/HelloProjectPage/download.html

How to download file with phantomjs ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [casperjs](/questions/tagged/casperjs) (based on [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs)) :

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

casper.start('https://deepak5j.github.io/HelloProjectPage/download.html', function() {
    var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deepak5j/WebImages/master/Tiles/';
    this.download(url, 'sun_tile.jpg');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: This is throwing lot of errors in eclipse.Can you write the correct code without any error

Comment: It runs without errors from command line : `casperjs download.js`. Which language are you using ? Java ???

Comment: yes.i am using java and using phantomjs.exe.Do i need to install casperjs

Comment: And don't you think this information are critical ? Always add all important information in your original post ! My code is javascript as phantomjs is

Answer (score 0):

Button click with phantom will not download file but after click you can get file as input stream. So you can save input stream to file. Code below will give an idea:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("Download")).click();
List<LogEntry> harLogEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("har").getAll();
LogEntry lastLogEntry = harLogEntries.get(harLogEntries.size() - 1);
String lastRequestUrl = getRequestUrlFromHarLogEntry(lastLogEntry);
DefaultHttpClient client;
HttpResponse response;
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(lastRequestUrl);
response = client.execute(get);
InputStream dataStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

I will share getRequestUrlFromHarLogEntry below:

```
private String getRequestUrlFromHarLogEntry(LogEntry logEntry)
        throws  Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> message = objectMapper.readValue(logEntry.getMessage(), Map.class);
    Map<String, Object> log = (Map<String, Object>) message.get("log");
    List<Object> entries = (List<Object>) log.get("entries");
    Map<String, Object> lastEntry = (Map<String, Object>) entries.get(entries.size() - 1);
    Map<String, Object> request = (Map<String, Object>) lastEntry.get("request");
    String url = (String) request.get("url");
    return url;
}
```

Hope this helps..